# data transfer using anchor tags

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am building a module in php in which i can see and access all the user on my website,For this i am importing all the names of the user from database and creating anchor links for them at the same time.Now i want to bind data to these links so that i can access that data on another page but the data should not be displayed in the URL I.E. i am looking for an alternate way for this pattern.since i don't want to share that data in URL.

loginatmpt.php?count='.$attempt.'

```html
<?php
if(!$result){
  echo 'Error fetching data';
  exit();
 }
 
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
  
  echo "<br><a href=mem_profile.php>".$row['firm_name']."</a>";
 }
 
?>
```

Comment: So you want a link that passes data to another page without appending it in the url. Not possible unless you use javascript to store the values in sessionStorage (or cookie etc)

Comment: You should use cookies or sessions for such transfers.

Comment: I was afraid of that since it will increase the number of calls to db.well ,If there is no way around it.Thanks atmd6

Comment: @Eternal1 yes i can use cookies but the problem is each link has unique data which should be passed to next page if a particular link is clicked.and i can't use session variable since every time it will be overwritten with new record.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to transmit the data but not have it in the URL, you could use HTTPPost (instead of GET, which is what you are doing when you add the parameters to the URL)
The data you transmit would still be visible in the source code though.
If you have a security issue (i.e. sensible data) you should not have it in the HTML (or javaScript) of your page at all, meaning to get that data from the server when it is needed (and properly authorized)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using **Session**.Just store your values in session then you can access them anywhere.For e.g.

Start Session at the top of your both page like

```
session_start();
```

Then assign values to session like

```
$_SESSION['YourVaraible'] = $YourVaraible; //As more as you have variables
```

Then at another page you just simply start Session in same way.Then use **$_SESSION['YourVaraible']** and every variable.Now you can use these value at any time in that page.

Comment: Thank you, but can you explain to me in above peace of code where i am calling each record and converting them to links wouldn't the $_SEESION variable be overwritten each time new record is extracted.since the data which i want to pass is sensitive and unique for each link how can i identify